# Beginner in TikZ: Replicating an easy graph nicely

Tags: tikz-pgf

It's my first plot and I tried to google for half an hour but couldn't figure out how to fix my attempt to replicate this graph. Could someone help me?

[image]

This is, what I have got:

Errors so far:

1. parabola (2,2)node[pos=0.8, right=10pt] {erfahren}; positioning doesn't work, anyways the parables are wrong
2. I couldn't find how to draw these parables, something like -((x-2)^2)+2

Thank you in advance !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

     \draw (0,0) -- (5,0) node[pos=0.5,below=14pt] {Zeit$\rightarrow$};
     \draw (0,0) -- (0,3) node[pos=0.5, left=10pt][text width=2cm]{$\uparrow$\\Emotionale\\Insensität};

     \draw (0,0) parabola (2,2)node[pos=0.8, right=10pt] {erfahren};
     \draw[dashed] (0,0) parabola (3,2)node[pos=0.5, right=10pt] {vorhergesagt};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. The change lines `\\ ` doesn't work. Use a `\parbox`. 2. Try `shift right=3pt`. 3. Take a look at the `Hobby` package for "freehand" drawing of graphs.

Comment: Well, changing the lines works if the node is aligned. Imho I would say `align=center` is better than using a `parbox` but then it's only a gut feeling (i. e. I don't have a concise point for or against either one).

Comment: @henry `align` or  `text width` keys switch the node `hbox` to a `minipage` which is a little better for node text control

Comment: thank you ! I edited the graph. could someone give me advice, how to draw this upside down parables? and how to put the nodes with an I (Time1/2/3/4)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a little TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Time axis
    \draw (0,0) -- node[below=1cm] {Time $\to$} (6,0);
    % Emotional axis
    \draw (0,0) -- node[left] {\parbox{2cm}{\centering $\uparrow$ \\ Emotional \\ intensity}} (0,4);
    % Time ticks
    \foreach \x [count=\j] in {0.2,3,4.5,6} {
        \draw (\x,0) coordinate (t\j) -- (\x,-0.1cm) node[below] (tt\j) {Time \j};
    }
    \node[below] at (tt1.south) {(Emotional event)};
    % Curves
    \draw (t1) .. controls +(1,2) .. node[above right] {Experienced} (t2);
    \draw[dashed] (t1) .. controls +(1,4) .. node[above right] {Predicted} (t4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: `\parbox` is not a TikZ solution! You may use `align=center` as node option instead.